# AFHTTPSessionManager throws "Request failed: service unavailable (503)" error intermittently

Tags: ios, objective-c

This issue is intermittent and I have no idea why this is happening. Basically, I am trying to add a new post by sending a POST request to a remote RESTful API. I checked with POSTMAN that there is no problem with the API at all, but AFNetworking seems to fail some of its requests for no reason.

Here's my complete code:

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *postBody = self.postInputField.text;
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"postBody": postBody};
    NetworkManager *manager = [NetworkManager sharedNetworkManager];

    [manager POST:NEW_POST_API_URL parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"NewPostSuccess. resp: %@", responseObject);
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ASK_TO_ADD_POST_ROW object:responseObject userInfo:nil];
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSString* ErrorResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", ErrorResponse);
    }];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:TABLE_SCROLL_TO_TOP object:nil userInfo:nil];
    }];
}
```

and here is the error:

```
com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x170429b40> { URL: http://192.168.0.102:3000/api/posts/new } { status code: 503, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain";
    Date = "Mon, 05 Oct 2015 03:15:37 GMT";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.0.102:3000/api/posts/new, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<556e6578 70656374 65642065 72726f72 2e>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: service unavailable (503)}
task: <__NSCFLocalDataTask: 0x136e6b150>{ taskIdentifier: 10 } { completed }
```

This happens intermittently, where I change nothing in the code and it starts working again in the same viewcontroller. The response error is useless as it only says `unexpected error`. Any guidance will be hugely appreciated.